# i have ishues when I try to run my hadoop aplication

Tags: hadoop

this is the problem ?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> hdfs namenode -format
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.
Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
       Please update C:\hadoop-3.3.1\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd
'-Dhadoop.security.logger' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

Comment: 1) Hadoop is not really designed to run on windows. You should try WSL2 instead 2) What is unclear about `JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set`? What did you set it to?

Comment: Hi thankx for your answer i set the envrnoment variable for java in my system variable and also i set the path and when i want to run my hadoop command so that i draw the always use it said that JAVA_HOME IS incorrectly set despite "that i have do the necessary configuration

Comment: i set for the variable  JAVA_Home =C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12    and in the path I have aded C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin

Comment: Hadoop does not like having spaces in environment variables. Also variables are case sensitive - JAVA_HOME is not the same as JAVA_Home. Plus, Hadoop 3.3.1 doesn't support Java 11

Comment: what you told me evrithing was good confugreed      I used JAVA_home  and each of variable envirenment in hadoop does't have space  so it's  just stiil change java 11 which java do you propose that it is suitable with hadoopb 3.1.1

Comment: Once again, it's spelled `JAVA_HOME`. I suggest you upgrade to Hadoop 3.3.4 which does support Java 11, not down all the way to 3.1.1